# What is the maximum amount of files GNU core utils can split a file into in 1gb filesize each?

Tags: split, coreutils

I want to know what kinds of limits i have . I saw it has a alphabet system a-z and then increment the second letter by 1 (xay -> xaz -> (havent seen but assume) xba -> xbb)

Comment: Check the `man split` page. The `-a` option lets you specify a suffix of any length (I assume up to 26), and other options allow for decimal and hex sequencing.

Answer (score 4):

split(1) will auto extend the suffix length by default (unless you specify a specific suffix length).
Therefore limits you might hit are, number of files on file system, file name length, file system size. Basically all file system limits, not split(1) limits.

Caveat, split(1) used to have a limit of 26^2, but I removed that by auto extending the suffixes in v8.16 (2012)

Answer (score 2):

That is effectively limited by the maximum number of files your file system supports, or the maximum possible input file size, not by `split`.

The suffix length is not a limitation that's relevant, as even with but 8 alphabetical suffix characters you could cover an input file larger than 2<sup>64</sup> bytes, because

1 GB • 26<sup>8</sup>

= 2<sup>30</sup> B • 26<sup>8</sup>

> 2<sup>30</sup> B • 16<sup>8</sup>

= 2<sup>30</sup> B • 2<sup>4•8</sup>

= 2<sup>64</sup> B

Reference: [`split.c`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/split.c), where they just do a loop of division by the number of letters in the alphabet to figure out how many letters they need.

Comment: Not sure how that division arithmetic could work in the presence of unknown quantities: reading unknown size from a pipe, or `--line-bytes` where the average line length is unknown. I can trigger `split: output file suffixes exhausted`. Without `-a`, it grows the suffix length from 1 up, with the result that the output file names are not in wildcard order. With `-d` and no `-a`, it "fixes" the sequence problem thus: it uses 2-digit suffixes up to `89`, then switches to 4-digit numbers starting at `9000` (and presumably 6-digit numbers after `9089` to `909000`).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant slightly confused here what you're remarking on! All I referred to is how you could easily calculate the suffix length yourself, and then I calculated that even for 2⁶⁴ long input, 8 letters would suffice.

Comment: Agreed if you already have the original file and a target output size, you can select the suffix length (trivially if you use decimal naming, or have 26 fingers to count on). If you are in production and receive data from external sources, it pays to be generous with the suffix length. I recall receiving software downloads split into 64KB chunks, uuencoded, and sent as 50 or so separate email attachments. I tried to invite the internet out to lunch once at a meeting in Aberdeen University: turned out that Janet was the Joint Academic Network, not the project librarian.

Comment: yep, that's what I meant: the "incredible generosity" of 8 letters allows for basically all of the world's data to be split into 1 GB files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this yourself trivially by generating (say) a 100kB file and writing files of (say) 2 bytes each:

```
mkdir try
cd try

dd if=/dev/urandom iflag=fullblock bs=1024 count=100 >random.dat
split -a4 -b2 random.dat
```

This will generate 51200 output files, starting with `xaaaa` and ending with `xcxtf`. See `man split` for the options.